# Apply vuejs transition-group to Bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, vuejs-transition

I am trying to apply vuejs transitions to Bootstrap grids but it totally screw up the grid system because the transition-group modifies the DOM and adds a new tag between the `row` and `col-md-6` tags. example:

```
<div class="row">
  <transition-group name="list">
    <div class="col-md-6" v-for="product in products" :key="product.id">\ 
      My product content here
    </div>
  </transition-group>
```

When this is rendered, it is modified to:

```
<div class="row">
  <span>
    <div class="col-md-6" v-for="product in products" :key="product.id">\ 
      My product content here
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

The new `span` tag messes up with the grid system, since `.col-md-6` is no longer a direct child of the `.row`.

Anyone knows a workaround for this that still uses Bootstrap grids?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can directly add a class to the transition-group.

By default a `span` is rendered by the `transition-group`. You change it with the `tag` attribute and simply add the `class="col-md-6"` like this:

```
<transition-group name="list" tag="div" class="col-md-6"></transition-group>
```